# 複数の列の条件から新しい列を作成する方法

Tags: r, tidyverse

sexが1、かつ、groupが3の場合に、新しい変数として「category」＝１、その他（sex=0, group=1,2）は0と作成したいです。ご教示お願い致します。

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:4, age = c(43, 62, 54, 55), sex = c(0, 1, 1, 0), group = c(1, 2, 3, 3)
    BP = c(120, 130, 132, 110), BMI = c(21, 26, 23, 19))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifelse` を使う場合。

```r
df <- df %>% mutate(category = ifelse(sex == 1 & group == 3, 1, 0))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ちなみにcase_whenでも作成可能性でしょうか？

Comment: はい、可能です。`mutate(category = case_when((sex == 1 & group == 3) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))`